# INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring

Tags: android, react-native, apk

¡Hola!

Me aparece este error al intentar generar un apk debug para actualizar una aplicación directamente en el dispositivo:

> Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
>
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException:
>   com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to finalize session :
>   INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package prensa.com signatures do
>   not match the previously installed version; ignoring!

Estoy seguro de que el código de la versión y el nombre de la versión se incrementaron y el nombre del paquete es el mismo.

Además, el keystore y otras claves son las mismas usadas anteriormente.

¿Dónde está el error?

Comment: yo quería instalar una app pero no me deja directo de play strore, así que la busque en el navegador y al momento de querer instalarla me decía que si quería instalar una actualización de esa app pero ni siquiera tengo la app, trate de instalar el apk con otra app y ahí me decía que la firma de la aplicación no coincide con la firma de una aplicación ya instalada con el mismo nombre de paquete, podrían decirme que puedo hacer por favor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se debe incrementar el [versionCode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html) para que se tome como un .apk de actualización pero en este caso indica que la firma es diferente.

Puede ser debido a estas causas:

> - El .apk esta firmado con un keystore de desarrollo y el .apk  instalado con uno de producción o viceversa.
> - El .apk esta firmado con un keystore de desarrollo y el .apk instalado con un keystore de desarrollo pero de otra pc.
> - El .apk fue instalado con otra sesión de tu dispositivo y no permitirá instalar otra versión hasta desinstalarla.

Si el .apk fue instalado con otra sesión de tu dispositivo, debes entrar desde configuración a aplicaciones, busca la aplicación, encontrarás este mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

da click en la aplicación y selecciona la opción "Desinstalar para todos los usuarios" ("Uninstall for all users).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: **CP, Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.